# Run controllers only after initialization is complete in AngularJS with angular-global-resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

I am having a problem where my controllers are running before initialization of my app, and I came across [this](https://github.com/v1per/angular-global-resolve) NPM package that works almost perfectly.  The only problem I'm having is the initialization function runs twice at almost the same time when the app starts.
Here is the relevant code:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, globalResolveProvider){

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/venues/feed');


  globalResolveProvider.addGlobalDependenciesTo($stateProvider, {
    getGlobalDependacies: function ($http, $rootScope, $cookies) {
      'ngInject';
      if ($rootScope.apiUrl){
        return
      }
      console.trace('do stuff')
        return $http.get('/__/env.json')
        .then(function(response) {
          $rootScope.apiUrl = response.data.apiUrl;
          $rootScope.googleMapsApiKey = response.data.googleMapsApiKey;
          $rootScope.currentLocationLat = 40.7589;
          $rootScope.currentLocationLng = 73.9851;
        })
        .then(function(){
          hotelId = ''
          if ($cookies.get('hotel') === undefined){
            $http.get($rootScope.apiUrl + '/hotels')
            .then(function(dbHotels){
              hotelId = dbHotels.data[0]._id
              $cookies.put('hotelId', hotelId)
            })
          }
          if ($cookies.get('userId') === undefined){
            $http.get($rootScope.apiUrl + '/users')
            .then(function(dbUsers){
              index = dbUsers.data.length - 1
              userId = dbUsers.data[index]._id
              $cookies.put('userId', userId)
              $rootScope.$broadcast('update-itinerary-icon')
            })
          }
        })
    }
  })

  $stateProvider
  .state('venues', {
    url: '/venues',
    abstract: true,
    template:'<div ui-view></div>'

  ....more states....

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Any Idea on why this might be running twice?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same problem now. Mine is even running three times!